# Multiplying bignums recursively

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion

I'm having some trouble figuring out how to multiply bignums recursively. For this problem, I have to input two strings using fgets and if the string consists of entirely digits, then I am to add the two "numbers" together recursively. I was able to do this part.

The next part is to then multiply the first number input from fgets by a character d, which is supposed to represent the numbers 2-9. I had to do this recursively as well. Lastly, the part I am stuck on is figuring out how to multiply these two numbers recursively.

For adding the two bignums together, I wrote a function that essentially traverses the numbers from right to left, adding the numbers as the recursion progresses and storing the result in a character array that grows over the time of the function. So essentially, my resultant array is in reverse order, meaning that the first element of my array is actually not the first number of the sum, but the last. However, I solved this problem by printing the elements in reverse order using a for loop.

For my recursive multiplication with a char d ranging from 2-9, I had a similar algorithm with the result in reverse order of the actual product, but again, I was able to solve this problem. Now I am having some trouble finding out how to multiply these two bignums together.

The idea I had was that I could somehow use the method of long multiplication/grade-school multiplication by calling my single-digit multiplication algorithm on the first string multiplied by the last element and second-to-last element of the second string, then call my sum function to add them together and store the result in a variable called accumulation then repeat this process in a recursion.

However, some problems I am having are that my single-digit multiplication recursive algorithms return the result in reverse order, so I cannot necessary add the two results together. Also, when multiplying the first string by the second-to-last element of the second string, I would have to multiply the result by 10 (since this digit is in the tens place), but I am not so sure how to implement that either.

Do you guys have any ideas on how I could possibly solve this problem using recursion only (no loops)? The result should look something like this:

```
First number > 57983985376

Second number > 543647645777735

Sum is 543705629763111

57983985376 times 2 is 115967970752

...

57983985376 times 9 is 521855868384

Product is 31522857142473014386403360
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. That is an intimidatingly large block of text.  Please break your text up into paragraphs.  That should be a minimum of 4 or 5 paragraphs, by the looks of it.

Comment: Also try considering the GMP (GNU Multiprecision) library.

Comment: @bb94: if the task is to multiply big numbers, your suggestion is great.  If, as I suspect, the task is to learn how to handle recursion, and the context used for that training is multiplying two bignums, then looking at the [GMP](http://gmplib.org/) code may help, but is likely to confuse.

Comment: Suggestion #1: write a function that can reverse a number.  That way you can get the "proper" results from your add and multiply-one-digit functions.  Suggestion #2: write a function that can multiply a number by a power of ten.  This function only needs to append zeroes to the end of an existing number.